# Synchronizable E-Mail Client

Tags: windows, linux, email, email-client

I need an e-mail client, such as ThunderBird, but with sync option.

By syncing, I mean syncing everything, such as read/unread mails, tags, tagged conversations, sent mails etc.

I have a desktop computer, let's call it D, and a notebook, let's call it L.

In D, I have carefully tagged each of my mails with 5 different tags.
However, in L, I need to create and manage tags one more.

I have sent a mail using D, and in L, the mail is not in Sent folder.

To sum up, I need a mail client that is able to sync everything, just like web browsers, both for Linux and Windows OS.

Comment: Have you tried this for TB? https://superuser.com/questions/354280/how-can-i-force-thunderbird-to-download-all-emails-by-imap

Comment: I don't have a real experience on this. But I can give you some pointers. You might consider using IMAP instead of POP3 which would sync your folder in both ways. Meanwhile, a work around this would be to sync your email data file it self using a3rd party software. Let's say you place you email data file in C:/ in both machines, then you can use a syncing app such as BitSync to directly sync the files so you will have the same data in both machines.

Comment: How are you downloading emails to your machines? Which email provider services are you using?

Comment: @danijelc I use POP3. The client is Zimbra.

Comment: Pop3 is the problem in your setup since when you download the emails arecdeleted from server. Second problem is most of desktop clients are making changes on their side and not servers. Now Thunderbird does sync folders, unread counts, sent emails and etc, but does not sync tags. I'm not aware of any email server with tagging options similar to Thunderbird. However by using imap protocol and Thunderbird you can come near to what you want. Thunderbird also allows export of its profile which my solve your needs. But I never used it in this way so unsure how tagging would work.